# If $f$ satisfies $\Delta f + |f|^{4/(N-2)}f=0$. Then what can say about $\|\nabla f\|_{L^2}$?

Tags: integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Let $f(x)= (1+ \frac{|x|^2}{N(N-2)})^{\frac{2-N}{2}}, (x\in \mathbb R^N).$

We note that $f$ satisfies the equation $\Delta f + |f|^{4/(N-2)}f=0$.

> My Question: Using  the above equation can we conclude that:
>   $$\int_{\mathbb R^N} |\nabla f|^2 = \int_{\mathbb R^N} |f|^{2N/(N-2)}$$? If yes, how?

Comment: $f$ is not integrable so the right hand side is $\infty$.

Comment: @AC: I think we can choose $N$ so that  RHS is finite.

Comment: @AC: Thanks: There was a typo in the definition  of $f$ have corrected it now.

Comment: $|f|^{\frac{2N}{N-2}} = (1+ |x|^2/C)^{2N}$ is not integrable.

Comment: @AC: It is $(1+ |x|)^{-2N}$. And so for large $N$ it  is integrable.

Comment: Try integrating by parts: $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|\nabla f|^2 = -\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} f\Delta f.$$ Then use the PDE.